# SSLSocket also for unsecure http?

Tags: java, ssl, https, certificate, jsse

Can I use SSLServerSocket class for both http and https sessions and listen to **one** port (with autodetection either the client comes with http or https)? Or it is obligatory to open **two** ports and use SSLServerSocket for https and ServerSocket for http?

Thanks

Comment: You would want to talk HTTP with a client on port 443 with `SSLServerSocket`? I'd be very surprised if that was possible, but by all means try it yourself.

Comment: Please check this answer I gave once, it might be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13450695/655756

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're trying to do is called *port unification*. It's [implemented in Grizzly](http://jfarcand.wordpress.com/2006/11/07/one-tcp-port-to-rule-them-all/) for example.

You can't really use an `SSLServerSocket` directly to listen to both HTTP and HTTPS traffic, since it would start the handshake straight upon reading, but you could have a plain `ServerSocket`, accept a plain `Socket`, try to detect when you get an TLS Client hello or an HTTP request by reading the first few bytes, and then [convert it to an `SSLSocket`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6564086/372643).

I can't say I've tried with `Socket`s, but you'll need something to read ahead the TLS Client Hello and push it back if necessary, [possibly using a `PushBackInputStream`, as suggested by EJP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11986016/372643).

(As far as I'm aware Grizzly uses `SSLEngine` instead of `SSLSocket` for this.)

Note that using port unification is quite unusual. I'm not sure what the overhead for reading ahead is. Using multiple ports instead is usually not a problem (in addition HTTP and HTTPS have different default ports, so you'd have to specify the port in at least one of the two URLs).