# How make SSL server socket support both http & https in java?

Tags: java, sockets, sslsocketfactory

I'm trying to create simple web server using java sockets which should support both http & https. But i can acheive only one at a time. I need to logic which supports both http @ port 80 & https @ port 443 at same time.

This is the sample code for HTTPS Server using sslsocket. We can acheive HTTP Server using simple ServerSocket.

```
public class HttpsServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        ks.load(new FileInputStream("/opt/p12file.p12"), "p12pass".toCharArray());
        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        kmf.init(ks, "p12pass".toCharArray());

        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sc.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null);

        SSLServerSocketFactory ssf = sc.getServerSocketFactory();
        SSLServerSocket s = (SSLServerSocket) ssf.createServerSocket(8080);

        while (true) {
            SSLSocket c = (SSLSocket) s.accept();
            BufferedWriter w = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(c.getOutputStream()));
            w.write("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
            w.newLine();
            w.write("Content-Type: text/html");
            w.newLine();
            w.newLine();
            w.write("<html><body><h1>Https Server Works</h1></body></html>");
            w.newLine();
            w.flush();
            w.close();
            c.close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Can anyone help me please??

Comment: Why are you not using a web container? Are you really trying to implement the http protocol on your own?

Comment: I'm trying to implement those feature in android app. @StevenPessall

Comment: An android app that is used as a HttpServer? To be honest that sounds like a messy system design.

Comment: Its not a full fledged HTTP Server in android. Just a Simple Background service which uses socket for getting httpresponse when something posted from browser. I achieved http server(based on socket) and https server(based on sslsocket) as android app seperatly. Now i want to merge those things. Thanks. @StevenPessall

Answer (score 2):

> How make SSL server socket support both http & https in java?

You can't. HTTP is plaintext, which `SSLServerSocket` cannot support.

> I'm trying to create simple web server using java sockets which should support both http & https. But I can achieve only one at a time. I need to logic which supports both http @ port 80 & https @ port 443 at same time.

You need:

- a plaintext `ServerSocket` listening at 80
- an `SSLServerSocket` listening at 443
- an accept-loop thread for each of these
- a connection thread per accepted socket.

You will never ever get it done inside a static `main()` method. I suggest you read the 'Custom Networking' section of the Java Tutorial, and then the JSSE Reference Guide.

You also of course need to take a really good look at RFC 2616 HTTP 1.1. It is extremely non-trivial to implement correctly.

As suggested in comments, you should really use something off-the-shelf.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

- Use two different ports, one for http and one for https.
- SSL Hello detection / Port unification:

  In HTTP and HTTPS the client is expected to talk first. So the server can use this to detect the protocol the client is expecting:

  - if the client sends a TLS ClientHello, then proceed with a TLS handshake;
  - if a plain HTTP request is sent instead, then handle the request as it is.

---

More information:

- [Can a Java server accept both SSL and plaintext connections on one port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985896/can-a-java-server-accept-both-ssl-and-plaintext-connections-on-one-port)
- [Is it possible to change plain socket to SSLSocket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559859/is-it-possible-to-change-plain-socket-to-sslsocket)